# What makes an android app "market" or "non-market"?

Tags: android, google-play

How does an Android device identify an app as "market" or "non-market"?

The situation is that I've an app I want to make available to a set of customers, rather than the entire world, but don't want them to have to go through the extra steps of allowing their device to install non-market apps.  I'd like to distribute it through a company website behind a login wall without losing the ease of installation for a play app.

The private channel, designed for companies to distribute internally, isn't quite what I had in mind.  I'm distributing to clients of my company, each of which has many employees, via a per-client website.

I don't have a problem with somehow presenting the app to Google to get it signed, sealed, etc.  "Why not just use the market" is a reasonable question, and I'm considering that option too.

I'd also rather not violate Google's terms of service in the process.

**Clarification:**
I appreciate the answers so far.  I am asking about the mechanism the Android OS uses to determine if something is a market app.

Comment: It might be better to ask this question on the [Android developers forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-developers).

Comment: Basically there is no difference: I uploaded the same package to Google Market and Android PIT and could distribute this package via any other platform. Only if you are using a *Application License Management* or *In-App payments*, there might be a difference 'cause different platforms use different libraries (e.g. Google Licensing, Samsung Zirconia, Android PIT library, ...). You can check the source with code I provided in the answer below.

Comment: Trinimon, for me the relevant difference is that a non-market installation requires the user to permit a non-market install.  I'd like to avoid that step if I can.  I understand that the extra step is there for the safety of the users, but in this case I am providing the app on an intranet without market access.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the right information:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String installationSource = pm.getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName());
```

A result *com.google.android.feedback* indicates, that the app was installed using Google Play.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

**p.s.** [this related link](http://www.strazzere.com/blog/2010/09/getinstallerpackagename-take-that-mr-pirate/) looks quite interesting

Comment: I've upvoted this because it is the sort of information I am looking for.  If we can confirm that getInstallerPackageName is what the OS uses to determine if it is a market app, I will turn the upvote into an accept.

Answer (score 0):

A "market" app is an app that you download from a trusted marketplace (usually Google Play but some devices like the Kindle Fire allow downloads from the Amazon market), so in your case you have to tell your users to allow installation of non-market apps.

What about showing the login screen on the app instead of the website? In this way you could publish it easily on Google Play. This is how 
similar apps do (like this one : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.intermedia.securisyncinternal.ui)

Comment: Regarding the login screen idea, imagine an app which serves as a portal to website A if you're in company A, website B in company B, or website C in company C.  If I provide a single app through a market, the user has ease of installation but needs to choose website A, B, or C.  If I provide differently configured apps for the three companies via websites A, B, and C, the users will have a harder installation, but will automatically get the right website.